# Difference between installing an app from eclipse, adb shell and app store (google play / Samsung app store)

Tags: android, google-play, android-install-apk

I have an application in which I also create a home screen shortcut. My app supports multiple languages. I am testing if I change the phone language, the home screen shortcut name is updating automatically or not.

If I install the app through eclipse, it works fine and home screen short name updates fine to new language automatically on device language change. But if I install the app through adb (using adb install), the home screen shortcut name does not update automatically on device language change.

So, is their any difference in the way we install app by following ways:

1. Installing through eclipse
2. Installing through adb shell
3. Installing through app store.

I try to install signed application in all cases. please help